# Is it possible to pass struct as a parameter of function in Solidity without using Libraries?

Tags: solidity, remix

Isnt it possible to do something like following in Solidity?
ps: i am taking example of "C" thinking it is somewhat similar to solidity. Correct me if i am wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct student
{
    char name[50];
    int roll;
};

void display(struct student stu);
// function prototype should be below to the structure declaration otherwise compiler shows error

int main()
{
    struct student stud;
    printf("Enter student's name: ");
    scanf("%s", &stud.name);
    printf("Enter roll number:");
    scanf("%d", &stud.roll);
    display(stud);   // passing structure variable stud as argument
    return 0;
}
void display(struct student stu){
  printf("Output\nName: %s",stu.name);
  printf("\nRoll: %d",stu.roll);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't run the contract and prompt for data entry in the same way, but you can write getter/setter functions to pass in the values for vaiables (or declare a var as public as I think this automatically creates a getter & setter in the compiler).

printf isn't something you'd use either, since there's nowhere to print to. You're only setting the values in the contract and/or reading them. Printing them out you'd do in a front end or something via web3.

But create a struct? Yes. Pass in values and update vars? Yes. Extract variable values? yes.